# Mix Android Style with my own

Tags: android, xml, styles, xamarin.android

Thats how my .axml looks like:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="Kommentare"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

As you see I'm accessing a style attribute that's defined in a style theme (`?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle`)

Now I would like to separate my own style:

```
  <style name="TextViewTitleBar" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
 </style>
```

and use it like:

`style="@style/TextViewTitleBar"` in my .axml , without losing the android defined style with the `?` at the beginning.

How to combine/mix these styles?

Comment: yep that worked. If you want, you can answer the question, so u will get some reputation though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent to

```
@android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle
```

Comment: its @ not ? ... forgot to mention this